# Partial Fraction Expansion (Solving Linear ODE with Laplace)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

I have a linear ODE initial value problem that I performed the laplace transform on and simplified it a bit, however now I am stuck at the partial fraction expansion.

[My workings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMpDO.png)

Note that C and R are constants too as well as the A and B from the partial expansion part

Comment: $$1/s(sR+1)=R\cdot (sR+1-sR)/sR(sR+1)$$

Comment: You have $A=C$ $AR+B=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Your Laplace transform is:

$$F(s)=\frac{C}{s(sR+1)}=\frac{\alpha}{s}+\frac{\beta}{sR+1}.$$

**Quick way using Euler's trick:**
Now, use Euler's trick. Multiply the equation by $s$ and set $s=0$ (zero of $s$) to obtain $\alpha =C$ and then multiply the equation by $sR+1$ and set $s=-1/R$ (zero of $sR+1$) to obtain $\beta=-RC$. This trick is always applicable for single zeros.

Note, if you do not like the idea of setting $s$ equal to the poles then you can do it more formally by taking the limit to the pole.

**The other method is not so quick and also more error prone:**

$$\frac{C}{s(sR+1)}=\frac{\alpha}{s}+\frac{\beta}{sR+1}=\frac{\alpha(sR+1)+\beta s}{s(sR+1)}$$

$$\implies \frac{C+s\cdot 0}{s(sR+1)}=\frac{\alpha +s(\beta+\alpha R)}{s(sR+1)}$$

Now, compare the numerators to obtain two equations:
$$C=\alpha \qquad \beta+\alpha R=0$$

Can you complete it from here?

Comment: Never used Euler's trick before. Is there another way of doing it?

Comment: Euler's trick is just a quick way to do partial fractions. It is very simple. Just try it (as explained in my answer) and you will see that it is very easy to apply. The other way would be to expand the right-hand side and compare coefficients.

Comment: Added the standard procedure.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much! Makes perfect sense now.

Comment: Actually, I'm having some trouble finding the inverse laplace of it, can't get it into the right form. I subbed the values for a and B back into the first equation but I can't get it into the form where I have a 1/s+1 type.

Comment: Rewrite $\frac{1}{Rs+1}=\frac{1}{R}\frac{1}{s+1/R}$ then use that $1/(s+a)$ has the laplace inverse $e^{-at}$ for $t\geq 0$, here we have $a=1/R$. Remember that constants can just be taken out ot the Laplace inverse.

Comment: Got it! Perfect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{C}{s(sR+1)}=\frac{A}{s} +\frac{B}{sR+1}=\frac{A (sR +1)+B s}{s(sR+1)}=\frac{A+(B+A R) s}{s(sR+1)}$$

$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
 A=C \\
 B+A R=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$

$A=C;\;B=-CR$

$$\frac{C}{s(sR+1)}=\frac{C}{s} -\frac{CR}{sR+1}$$